# Django-Python:The user image is not displayed on the user page when logged in with user details

Tags: python, html, django, django-views, django-templates

When a user logs in, I want to see their profile picture if they have one; if not, the default profile picture should be displayed.

Here is my  view.py

````
def header(request):
    if request.session.has_key('id'):
        user_id = request.session['id']
        user = registertb.objects.get(id=user_id)
        return render(request, 'headerfooter.html', {'user_image': user})
    else:
        return render(request, 'headerfooter.html')`
```


HTML CODE

```
<li>
                        
    <p style="width:30px; height:30px; margin-left: 200px; margin-top: 10px;color: black;">{{ i.User_name }}</p>
    {% if user.user_image %}
        <img src="{{ i.user_image.url }}" style="height: 50px; width: 50px;" alt="Default Image">
    {% else %}
        <img src="/media/image/New folder/default-avatar-profile.jpg" style="height: 50px; width: 50px;" alt="Default Image">
    {% endif %}
 </li>`
```

 models.py

```
class registertb(models.Model):
    User_name=models.CharField(max_length=300)
    User_email=models.CharField(max_length=300)
    user_image=models.ImageField(upload_to='image/')
    password=models.CharField(max_length=400)
    conf_password=models.CharField(max_length=300)
`
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a small change to your code.

```
def user_image(request):
    user_img = None

    if 'id' in request.session:
        user_id = request.session['id']
        try:
            user = registertb.objects.get(id=user_id)
            if user.user_image:
               user_img = user.user_image.url
        except registertb.DoesNotExist:
            pass

    return {'user_img': user_img}
```

try this, it will work.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there might be a mismatch between the variable names used in your view function and the variable names used in your HTML template. In your view function, you are passing the user object using the key 'user_image', but in your template, you are trying to access it using user.
if you are passing 'user_image' should use image 'user_image.user_image.url' in template

Comment: Hi,
I appreciate the suggestions, but unfortunately, the issue still persists.  Following your advise, I tried user to use_image.user image.url, however it didn't fix the issue.

Comment: looking your html code section and change i.user_image.url to user_image.user_image.url. because you are passing the user details using the variable user_image

Comment: Hi , Hello, it's functioning now, however the default picture isn't showing up. I've altered my code instead view.py . I called context_processor.py .

Answer (score 1):

It's functioning now, however the default picture isn't showing up. And also I've altered my code, instead of view.py. I called context_processor.py.

```
def user_image(request):
    user_img = None

    if 'id' in request.session:
        user_id = request.session['id']
        try:
            user = registertb.objects.get(id=user_id)
            user_img = user.user_image.url
        except registertb.DoesNotExist:
            pass

    return {'user_img': user_img}
```